# how network stream is detecting disconnection

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, network-programming

i have started studying socket programming recently and wrote a simple async tcp server which can send an receive from individual clients just fine. here is the simplified code for it:

```
//accpet loop

while (true)
{
   var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
   new AppClient(client).Start();
} 

 // and here is the start method in AppClient class
 public async void Start()
 {
        /// TcpClient is a class property which is in scope of this method
       using (var stream = TcpClient.GetStream())
       {
           string message = string.Empty;
           byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
           int bytesRead = 0;
           while (true)
           {
                try
                {
                    bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }         
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        break;
                 }

                 // decode simple text message
                 message += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);


           }
       }
  }
```

it handles thousands of connection in a single threaded fashion but
what makes me upset is that no matter how i destroy the client (killing process and ...) the **ReadAsync** method immediately throws an exception which basically conflicts with my thoughts. 
(as far as i read detecting disconnected socket in tcp should not be that easy)

am i doing some thing wrong?

Comment: You really shouldn't do `catch (Exception ex)` - it's such an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks, i ll remember that.

Comment: For what he is doing there is absolutely nothing wrong with catching Exception

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [`.ReadAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193669(v=vs.110).aspx) with the cancellationToken. Then change you loop to also check the token value.  When you want to kill the client you then signal the token.

Also check your variable `bytesRead`.  If it returns as `0` the connection just closed.

Comment: thanks a lot for the cancelation tip. however bytesRead is never zero, the ReadAsync method with await pauses the method until there is some thing to read btw.

Comment: It will return 0 if the server side disconnects.

Answer (score 1):

> what makes me upset is that no matter how i destroy the client
>   (killing process and ...) the ReadAsync method immediately throws an
>   exception

Welcome to Network(Socket) Programming. You've to make yourself comfortable with these exceptions as it is very usual to face exceptions in these type of applications. This behaviour is by design.

It is your application which should be developed in such a matter that the end-user gets good message, instead of the message of exceptions.

> ...the ReadAsync method immediately throws an exception which
>   basically conflicts with my thoughts. (as far as i read detecting
>   disconnected socket in tcp should not be that easy)

The reason for this is :

The [`TcpClient.Connected Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected(v=vs.110).aspx) gets the connection state of the Client socket as of the last I/O operation. When it returns false, the Client socket was either never connected, or is no longer connected.

***Because the Connected property only reflects the state of the connection as of the most recent operation, you should attempt to send or receive a message to determine the current state.*** After the message send fails, this property no longer returns true.

**Note that this behaviour is by design.** You cannot reliably test the state of the connection because, in the time between the test and a send/receive, the connection could have been lost. Your code should assume the socket is connected, and gracefully handle failed transmissions.

Comment: thanks for the response, is it ok that have await stream.ReadAsync() in that infinite loop? (i did that to keep listening for new data from client)

Comment: @SHM - Yes, it is OK. If client is to send data that many times which is not known beforehand, then yes, you've to keep waiting and receiving data. As soon as the client closes the socket, your loop would break, thereby throwing exception.

Comment: @SHM - Also, re-read my answer's last 2 paragraphs carefully, and with patience. Those are very helpful words. Good Luck for your experience with network-programming.

Comment: yeah i read that, however gracefully close = sending a close packet. now if a client dose not get a chance to send that close packet overt tcp, how dose ReadAsync throws "forcibly closed Exception" ?

Comment: @SHM - What do you mean by *if a client dose not get a chance to send that close packet overt tcp, how dose ReadAsync throws "forcibly closed Exception"*? Quoting for you what MSDN source says : `The Close method marks the instance as disposed and requests that the associated Socket close the TCP connection. Based on the LingerState property, the TCP connection may stay open for some time after the Close method is called when data remains to be sent. There is no notification provided when the underlying connection has completed closing. `

Comment: @SHM - Calling this method will eventually result in the close of the associated Socket and will also close the associated NetworkStream that is used to send and receive data if one was created.` I hope this is what you wanted to be clarified. If client sends close(), then either the close() packet would be delivered or exception would be thrown; since it is TCP. **If the client doesn't send close() and simply end the program**, then the server would fetch exception because one-endpoint of the connection has been terminated. Server can't read/write messages now,thereby resulting in exception`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't "detecting" the disconnection, it trhows and exception because `.ReadAsync` is constantly trying to get if there's data avaiable for reading, if there is write it into the buffer, if the data length == buffer length then end the function. All this steps (probably there's more) involve the `Stream` , which is bound to the `socket`. Then, if the socket is closed(by code or manually), the stream is closed, if you try to do anything with a closed stream a exception will be thrown.

Comment: Readasync checks only once im awaiting it, once data is available on the socket the rest of method id executed.